# How do you pull guest and host restource utilization data from Suse Cloud OpenStack

Tags: openstack, opensuse

I am trying to pull guest and physical server resource utilization from the Suse Cloud OpenStack Infrasructure. In vMWare world, I would connect to vcenter can try to pull the data from performance manager or quick stats.

Can any body provide some insight about Suse Clould, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways I'd go about it:

- VM performance characteristics available in dashboard
- install Telemetry (ceilometer) which should add even more info
- if you want real low-level information - on compute nodes install "virt-top" (whatever package provides that tool in SuSE - you'll have to install it). Then using virt-top you'll see activity of all the VMs
- use virt-manager. This one could be installed on some certal "control" node.

  - add connections to your compute nodes
  - enable CPU/RAM/Net stats in preferences
  - watch performace stats real time for each node.

Comment: I would like to pull data to an external repository. Are you aware of any packages for python that does this already?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. However I have never investigate  such possibility.